# Are dots of a different color in midst of a closed circuit removed?

Tags: dots

When you close a boundary which has dots of different colors in midst of them, are these different color dots deleted and counted as score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

An example:

[image: Before match] [image]

The red dot in the middle of the yellow square would be on the bottom row in the second image, if it weren't destroyed.

In addition, the animation highlighting each dot of the loop's colour also plays for dots contained within the loop